# Como visualizar resultado de query no SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Para visualizar tabelas eu uso um plugin chamado QuestoIdPlugin e funciona muito bem, mas e para visualizar resultados de queries, tem alguma coisa?

Comment: Segue o link da documentação para adicionar o plugin no eclipse: http://tylerfrankenstein.com/browse-android-emulator-sqlite-database-eclipse

Comment: Deseja visualizar pelo SQLiteBrowser ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor;

select_query = "SELECT a,b,c FROM table";

        cursor = db.rawQuery(select_query, null);

        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
           while (cursor.moveToNext()) { //se a select devolver várias colunas
            cursor.moveToFirst();
```

De acordo com o tipo de dados das colunas que a query vai retornar, utilizas o seguinte comando para obter a coluna (neste caso se for double, se for String é getString...)

```
cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(nome_da_Coluna)))
} //fim do while
} //fim do if
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use um cursor para retornar os resultados da sua QUERY**

*Exemplo:*

```
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
```

Com isso você pode usar o "c" para retornar seus resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar a class `DatabaseHelper` criando um objeto `db` usando `helper.getReadableDatabase()`, como mostro no exemplo abaixo.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, tipo_viagem, destino, " +
"data_chegada, data_saida, orcamento FROM viagem",
null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

viagens = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
    Map<String, Object> item =new HashMap<String, Object>();

    String id = cursor.getString(0);
    int tipoViagem = cursor.getInt(1);
    String destino = cursor.getString(2);
    long dataChegada = cursor.getLong(3);
    long dataSaida = cursor.getLong(4);
    double orcamento = cursor.getDouble(5);
    item.put("id", id);

    if (tipoViagem == Constantes.VIAGEM_LAZER) {
        item.put("imagem", R.drawable.lazer);
    } else {
        item.put("imagem", R.drawable.negocios);
    }

    item.put("destino", destino);

    Date dataChegadaDate = new Date(dataChegada);
    Date dataSaidaDate = new Date(dataSaida);

    String periodo = dateFormat.format(dataChegadaDate) +
    " a " + dateFormat.format(dataSaidaDate);

   item.put("data", periodo);
   double totalGasto = calcularTotalGasto(db, id);
   item.put("total", "Gasto total R$ " + totalGasto);
   double alerta = orcamento * valorLimite / 100;
   Double [] valores =
   new Double[] { orcamento, alerta, totalGasto };
   item.put("barraProgresso", valores);
   viagens.add(item);
   cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();
```

Agora você só precisa adaptar a sua necessidade.